Huffman encyption coding program runs for too long
I have a c program that attempts implementing Huffman encryption. The problem is that the program runs indefinity after asking for the file containing the string to be encrypted is entered.
i'm not sure what' causing this isue. I have included the file with the string in the same directory as the program.
Below is the program:


 #include <stdio.h> /*rewind, */
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h> /*system, */


/*Please change name of *node*/
 typedef struct node_t {
    char c;
    int frequency;
    struct node_t *left, *right;
 } *node;

 /*global variable: track num of nodes,, end of que, pool of nodes? 
    string array for codes of each letter*/

    int n_nodes = 0;
    int qend = 1;
    struct node_t pool[256] = {{0}};
    node qqq[255], *q = qqq - 1;
    char *code[128]= {0};
    char buffer[1024];
    int input_data = 0;
    int output_data = 0;



/*function prototypes*/
node newNode(int frequency, char c, node a, node b);
void qinsert(node n);
node qremove();
void buildCode(node n, char *s, int len);
void importFile(FILE *fp_in, unsigned int *frequency);
void encode(FILE* fp_in, FILE* fp_out, unsigned int *frequency);
int printable(int c);
void printCode(unsigned int *frequency);


 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE *fp_in, *fp_out;
    char file_name[50] = {0};
    unsigned int frequency[128] = {0}, i;

    /*System functinon executes a shell command in a C function*/
    system("clear");
    printf("**************************************************************\n");
    printf("**************************************************************\n");

    if (argc == 2) {
        /*commandline argument directly allows to compress the file*/
        strcpy(file_name, argv[1]);
    }
    else if (argc > 2){
        printf("Too many arguments supplied. \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Please enter the file to be compressed: ");
        scanf("%s", file_name);
    }
    if (strlen(file_name)>= 50){
        printf("ERROR: Enter a filename less than 50 chars");
        return 0;
    }
    /*import the file into the program and update the huffman tree*/
    if((fp_in = fopen(file_name, "r")) == NULL){
        printf("\nError: No such file\n");
        return 0;
    }    

    importFile(fp_in, frequency);

    printCode(frequency);

    /*Encode and save the encoded file under the .huffman extension*/
    strcat(file_name, ".huffman");
    fp_out = fopen(file_name, "w");
    encode(fp_in, fp_out, frequency);

    fclose(fp_in);
    fclose(fp_out);

    strcat(file_name, ".table");
    fp_out = fopen(file_name, "w");
    for(i = 0; i < 128; i++){
        fprintf(fp_out, "%c", (char)frequency[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp_out);
    printf("\nInput bytes: %d\n", input_data);
    output_data = (output_data % 8)? (output_data / 8) + 1: (output_data / 8);
    printf("Output bytes: %d\n", output_data);

    printf("\nCompression ratio: %.2f%%\n\n\n", ((double)(input_data-output_data)/input_data)*100);
    return 0;
 }


/*Fucntion to creatre a new node*/
node newNode(int frequency, char c, node a, node b){

    node n = pool + n_nodes++;
    if (frequency != 0){
        /*Assign character 'c' to the character of the node,
          assign frequency*/
        n->c = c;
        n->frequency = frequency;
    }
    else {
        /*If there is no frequency provided, removed nodes at the end of
          the que will be added to left and right*/
        n->left = a;
        n->right = b;
        n->frequency = a->frequency + b->frequency;
    }

    return n;
}

/*Function to insert a node into the priority que*/
 void qinsert(node n){

    int j, i = qend++;
    while ((j = i/2)){
        if (q[j]->frequency <= n->frequency){
            break;
        }
        q[i] = q[j];
        i = j;
        
    } 
    q[i] = n;
 }

 node qremove(){

    int i, l;
    node n = q[i = 1];

    if (qend < 2){
        return 0;
    }
    qend--;
    while ((l = i * 2) < qend){
        if (l + 1 < qend && q[l + 1]->frequency < q[l]->frequency){
            l++;
            q[i] = q[l];
            i = l;
        }
    }  
    q[i] = q[qend];
    return n;
 }

 /*Assign the code for each char of the input string*/
 void buildCode(node n, char *s, int len){

    static char *output = buffer;
    if (n->c){
        s[len] = 0;
        strcpy(output, s);
        code[(int)n->c] = output;
        output += len + 1;
        return;        
    }

    /*Recursion is used to write out the code, if right add 1, if right add a 0*/

    s[len] = '0'; 
    buildCode(n->left, s, len + 1);
    s[len] = '1';
    buildCode(n->right, s, len + 1);

 }

 void importFile(FILE* fp_in, unsigned int *frequency){
    /*temporary variables*/
    char c, s[20] = {0}; 
    int i = 0;
    printf("Read file: \n");

    while((c = fgetc(fp_in)) != EOF){
        /*Read the file character by character and increment the frequency*/
        frequency[(int)c]++;
        putchar(c);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++){
        if (frequency[i]){
            /*If there is a frequency, insert new node*/
            qinsert(newNode(frequency[i], i, 0, 0 ));
        }
    }
    while (qend > 1){
        /*Build tree*/
        qinsert(newNode(0, 0, qremove(), qremove()));
        /*Build the code for the characters*/
        buildCode(q[1], s, 0);
    }
    

 }

 void encode(FILE* fp_in, FILE* fp_out, unsigned int *frequency){

    unsigned char buffer = 0;
    int bits = 0;
    int lim = 0;
    int i;
        rewind(fp_in);
    
    for(i = 0; i < 128; i++){
        if(frequency[i]){
            lim += (frequency[i]*strlen(code[i]));
        } 
    }
    output_data = lim;
    fprintf(fp_out, "%04d\n", lim);
    printf("\nEncoded: \n");

    int in;
    while ((in = fgetc(fp_in)) != EOF){
        char *temp = code[in];
        for (i = 0; temp[i] != '\0'; i++){
            if (temp[i] == '1'){
                buffer |= (1 << (7-bits));
            }
            bits++;

            if(bits == 8){
                fputc(buffer, fp_out);
                buffer = 0;
                bits = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("%s", code[in]); 
    }
    if(bits > 0){
        fputc(buffer, fp_out);
    }
    else if (in == EOF && bits > 0){
        fputc(buffer, fp_out);
    }

 }

 int printable(int c){
    return (c >= 32 && c <= 126);
 }

 void printCode(unsigned int *frequency){
    int i;
    printf("\n--------------CODE TABLE--------------\n --------------"
            "--------------\n CHAR FREQ CODE\n --------------\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 128; i++){
        if(printable(i) && code[i] != NULL && i != ' '){
            printf("%-4c  %-4d  %16s\n", i, frequency[i], code[i]);
        }
        else if (code[i]!= NULL){
            switch(i){
                case '\n':
                    printf("\\n ");
                case ' ':
                    printf("\' \' ");
                    break;
                case '\t':
                    printf("\\t  ");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("%0X  ", (char)i);
                    break;
            }
            printf(" %-4d  %16s\n", frequency[i], code[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("--------------\n");
 }



What does the line while (qend > 1) i importFile do?

Huffman coding is not encryption.

For qinsert(newNode(0, 0, qremove(), qremove())), the first argument needs to be the sum of the frequencies of two nodes removed.

In importFile, c is a char and should be int. You do this correctly in encode with int in; Otherwise, when reading in binary data with fgetc, a valid data byte of 0xFF will be seen (erroneously) as a premature EOF, so you won't read in the entire file.

Side note: You check to ensure that file_name has a length < 50. But, after that, you strcat onto it .huffman. This is UB because you can overflow file_name (e.g. suppose the length is 48). Try keeping the 50 limit but change to char file_name[60]; to allow space for the file suffix you add.

You're getting "too cute" in qremove with node n = q[i = 1]; Replace with int i = 1; node n = q[i]; But, in qremove, the loop never ends. i is always 1 and [therefore] l is always 2 because of: while ((l = i * 2) < qend).  IMO, this is also "too cute". I'd replace this with a proper for loop: for (l = i * 2; l < qend; l = i * 2). On the first iteration, the if fails and, so, l is never incremented and i is never changed. I found this by running under gdb with a breakpoint on qremove. Then, I added some debug printf statements.

I stopped there. But, the first thing in qremove is if (qend < 2) return 0; But, in importFile, you have while (qend > 1). With these two things, the outer loop may never terminate???

Also, [again, "too cute"]: qinsert(newNode(0, 0, qremove(), qremove())); has a sequence point problem. [AFAIK], the order of which qremove is called is either UB or implementation defined. Replace this with: node r1 = qremove(); node r2 = qremove(); qinsert(newNode(0, 0, r1, r2)); This guarantees proper/desired order. Otherwise, with your code, the args could be [effectively] r1,r2 but they could be r2,r1

If I'm interpreting Mark's comment correctly, to get the sum of the frequencies of nodes removed, we'd have to do the r1/r2 so we can get the correct sum (e.g.) r1 = ...; r2 = ...; sum = r1->frequency + r2->frequency; qinsert(newNode(sum,0,r1,r2));

@CraigEstey Yes, that's correct. The order of the two nodes does not matter, but you need to sequence the removals anyway in order to compute the sum of the frequencies.
